# Rails: Routing Error for Signout link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Hi so I'm working on chapter 8.2.6 of Hartl's Rails tutorial

My application fails a test that I wrote for testing the 'sign out' link.

Here is a copy of my command prompt

```
C:\Sites\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/
.............F.................................

Failures:

  1) Authentication signin with valid information followed by signout
     Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign out" }
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       uninitialized constant SessionController
     # ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (5 levels) in <to
p (required)>'

Finished in 1.17 seconds
47 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb:36 # Authentication signin with
 valid information followed by signout
```

Here is the relevant part of the test code (spec/requests/authenticate_pages_spec.rb)

describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
   end

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

config/routes

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do 
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'session#destroy',      via: 'delete'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indicator here is `uninitialized constant SessionController`.

Your controller name is plural, `SessionsController`

If you look at your `routes.rb` file, you will notice your typo.

```
match '/signout', to: 'session#destroy',      via: 'delete'
```

which should look like this:

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',      via: 'delete'
```

Comment: nice catch, one of those typos that you could look at for hours and not see

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!  I spent a ton of time re-reading my files and couldn't find it.